# Query to return a table generates SQL ERROR (1064): Error in syntax

Tags: mysql, function

I'm trying to create a function, but keep getting the error message that

*SQL ERROR (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the       manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right     syntax to use near "at line 3.*

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS mysql.HelpMePlz$$

CREATE FUNCTION mysql.HelpMePlz(input VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)       BEGIN
        DECLARE result VARCHAR(255);

        SELECT name into result 
        FROM tb_company 
        WHERE company_info = input
        LIMIT 3

        RETURN result;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: why limit 3? are you returning a table or a value?

Comment: The result is supposed to be more than a value... so It has to be a table

Comment: Ya so basically you are wanting a table valued function

Comment: Look it up first...

Comment: sorry.. what do you mean by that...?

Comment: There is no table valued function in mysql so you will need to insert data to a proper table.... you call the procedure to insert into a new table and not expecting a return